# How do I upload a non-live website for users to view

Tags: html, web, ftp

I'm looking for information on how a person typical uploads the HTML file of there website to share with other users on message boards(Graphic Design forums)

I already have my original website live but have started to add features and have trouble fixing the problems. I have posted on numerous sites and all the members say they want to help but need to see the code live.

(Hard code) won't help or work for them?

Where do I upload the site? Would I then provide a link or url?

Being it's public forums I can't use a FTP program right? because they could do anything afterwards to my site having the username/password.

I'm just very lost,doing a preview in firefox with Dreamweaver cs6 is so simple but trying to share with everybody makes no-sense.

thank you

Comment: You need a machine that is always connected to the internet, running an HTTP server application like Apache. This is called a webserver. You can buy or rent one, or maybe find some for free (where your site usually gets displayed in an iframe, surrounded by ads, and those usually lack support for serverside programming languages like PHP and ASP.NET). If you found such a webserver, you'll have to upload your files by the way they provide you. This can be through FTP or by uploading files with the browser. Other people then can view your site without the FTP password. Anyway, offtopic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

So it's just plain HTML/CSS/JS?
Use http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

If your website is already live and on the web, you don't need to upload anything.  All anyone needs to do to see your code is to look at your site with a browser and press CTRL+U to see the live html, javascript, CSS etc.

Unless there is a special reason they need to see static code ~ which you can easily upload to http://pastebin.com/ ~  that should suffice.

Terence.